# Is there a way to leave Grandship before fighting the Demolisher?

Tags: bravely-default

I'm near the end of the game, in Grandship, right before fighting the Demolisher of World Bounds.

Apparently I can't get out, and I must fight the boss at the deck. Is there a way to leave?

I'm not *stuck* in the game progress, because Grandship has sutain (market for items and dungeon for levels), plus I have almost all the jobs anyway. But I wanted to do some side events first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the event that lands you at this particular point in the game, the Grandship sustains heavy damage and cannot be navigated without extensive repairs. Said repairs are, of course, *only* completed after you win the battle with the Demolisher of World Bounds. (Bonus points for averting spoilers by using the title instead of the enemy's name, by the way.) Until then, you're basically stuck.

Whether or not the side events you didn't complete before this crucial point will be available afterwards, however, is something I do not know. Unless someone else provides that helpful tidbit, I'm guessing the easiest way to find out is to see the boss fight through.

Comment: IIRC, the only change is that the final dungeon opens. I think you should be able to finish the remaining side quest, after getting rid of the menace on your deck.